# Xcode -- reveal a file in the groups&files panel

Tags: xcode

I have an Xcode project with (currently) about 300 files.  Is there an easy way to reveal a specific file in the Groups&Files panel, assuming I remember the name of the file, but not where it is located?

I don't care if I *open* the file or not.  But I do need to *reveal* it.  In other words, I need the file's group to be opened in the Groups&Files panel, and the file to be highlighted within the group.  So "quick open" (shift-apple-d) does not fit the bill, because it opens the file without revealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

1. Select the root in the Groups & Files list.
2. Type the name in the project windows's search field.
3. You should now see the file in the list on the right.  Right-click it and choose "Reveal in Group Tree".

Comment: Thank you!   Fixes the "needle in a haystack" problem of a heavily folderized large project